# C# Property inheritance question

Tags: c#, .net

How do i inherit a property in c# from an interface and give that property other name on the class?

For example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
  int Num {get;set;}
}

public class IFooCls : IFoo
{
  int Ifoo.Num{get;set}
}
```

In this case, what the property name in the interface is also the same in the class. What i want is to give other property name on the class but still pointing to "Num" in the interface in this case. In VB, we can do it like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property UserId() As String Implements System.Security.Principal.IIdentity.Name
    Get
        Return _userId
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Maybe by explaining exactly what you want to do, you may get some better advise, because as @Oded has said, this goes against what Inheritence is

Comment: ok, what i really wanted is this, i need to implement System.Security.Principal.IIdentity. It has a Name Property. But i was doing a custom identity class, and i wanted that the Name property on that class will be changed to UserID instead.

Comment: In VB we can do it like the above code. Is there a straightforward way of doing the above vb code in c#. I know we can have work around in this one by adding other property like what @Igor Zevaka posted below.

Comment: This is a terrible feature of VB that leads to highly confusing and horrible code. If the property name doesn't fit the implementing cases, I think you should have a look at your abstractions rather than trying to shoehorn implementations into them.

Comment: @Banang, i agree with you. But the VB implementation has merits. System.Security.Principal.IIdentity is a library and we cant just change that. It would be awkward on our class if the will be using Name property but we are dealing with UserID. It would bring more confusion later on the development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inherit a property, you inherit it, name, type and all. There is no way to change the name.

If you want, you can write another property with a different name and call the inherited property from it (you still have to implement the original property).

See what you *can* do on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) MSDN page.

The only way to achieve what you want (have a `UserId` property *and* impelement `IIdentity`) is to call `IIdentity.Name` from it).

This will hide the `IIdentity.Name` property from users of your class (unless they cast to `IIdentity`):

```
public class myIdentity : IIdentity
{
   public string IIdentity.Name {get; set;}

   public string UserId 
   { 
      get 
      { 
        return IIdentity.Name;
      }

      set 
      { 
        IIdentity.Name = value;
      }
}
```

Comment: this is what we were currently doing.

Comment: @mcxiand - That's the only way you could, in C#. The only other "solution" would be to implement it in a VB.NET project and reference that project in your C# projects ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to simulate what you are trying to do in C#

```
public interface Foo {
  string Name {get;set;}
}

pubilc class Bar : Foo {

#region Foo implementation
  public string Name {get{return UserName;} set{UserName = value;}}
#endregion //Foo implementation

  public string UserName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You can use explicit implementation of the interface to "hide" the `Name` member from users of the `Bar` class. I believe this is how VB.NET does it's thing under-the-hood.